# Angular FormControl, patchValue and mat-selection-list

Tags: angular, form-control

All I want for now is to have a form w/ a `mat-selection-list`.

This is the code.

**.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="aForm">
 <mat-selection-list #id matInput #idInput formControlName="id" style="width: 20%">
        <mat-list-option #matOption *ngFor="let option of Options" [value]="option"
          (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); changeSelectedOption(matOption.value)" checkboxPosition="before">
          {{ option }}
        </mat-list-option>
      </mat-selection-list>
</form>
```

**.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';

...

export class AComponent implements OnInit {
aForm: FormGroup;

Options: string[] = ['exclude', 'include', 'excludeDateTtime']

constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {

    this.aForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fc: new FormControl({ value: 'exclude', disabled: false }),
    });
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  changeSelectedOption(option: any) {

    this.aForm.controls['fc'].patchValue('exclude');
  }

}
```

**Problem 1: initializing `formControl`**

In line `fc: new FormControl({ value: 'exclude', disabled: false }),` if I provide a value other then `''` it throws an error `ERROR TypeError: t._value.some is not a function`.

**Problem 2: updating `formControl` value**

For look & feel reasons I use the `mat-selection-list` w/ `[multiple]="true"` and try to override the multiple selections w/ function `changeSelectedOption` so that, only one option can be picked up in the end.

In line, `this.aForm.controls['fc'].patchValue('exclude');` setting the `'exclude'` value throws the error `ERROR TypeError: t.forEach is not a function`.

What do these errors mean? What can I do to solve them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As is said in some other related questions on StackOverflow, for the `formControl.patchValue()` to work, the passed argument needs to have the expected data type.

The problematic lines I mention above e.g. `fc: new FormControl({ value: 'exclude', disabled: false }),` show arguments w/ data type `string` i.e. `'exclude'`.

However, for `mat-selection-list` the expected data type is `Array` whether you specify `[multiple]="true"` or `[multiple]="false"`. I suppose the same holds for all other Angular-Material lists.

Hence the right way, is

`fc: new FormControl({ value: ['exclude'], disabled: false }),`

and

`this.aForm.controls['fc'].patchValue(['exclude']);`

Given the opportunity, using `''` in `fc: new FormControl({ value: '', disabled: false }),`

it does not mean the data type is `string`. Put differently, `''` is not the empty string implying thus a `string` data type. It seems to work more as an `any` "object" or to denote an object of `any` type.